# tmux bind-key to kill all or maybe a grouping of windows/panels

Tags: bash, terminal, exit, tmux, quit

I've created a script that opens up tmux and splits into 4 windows/panels, but i was wondering if theres a quick way to exit them all, preferably via a key binding.
Thanks.

[Edit]

What i'm looking for is a way to exit a selection of windows via a key binding.
Something maybe i can add to my .tmux.conf file like:
`bind-key C-c exit-all`
Or maybe a command i can pass in after setting up the split windows etc like: `tmux bind-key C-c exit-all`

*I'm putting exit-all as the command there as thats what im looking for, but i don't know the real name for this function or way of doing this*

Comment: Something like `new-session`? Or `detach`? It's not clear what you have or are looking for.

Comment: Please post the script and as @Nick said it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry but why was this downvoted?

@Nick - Like detach, but to actually exit/kill them all.
I'm thinking its best to just loop them and exit each like that.

@ 에이바 - the rest of the script doesn't matter, i'm just looking for a way in tmux to bind some keys to exit/kill the windows, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man tmux`:

```
unlink-window [-k] [-t target-window]
              (alias: unlinkw)
        Unlink target-window.  Unless -k is given, a window may be unlinked only if it is linked to multiple ses-
        sions - windows may not be linked to no sessions; if -k is specified and the window is linked to only one
        session, it is unlinked and destroyed.
```

I think `unlink-window -k` is what you're after.

Comment: Thanks Nick, that works great at exiting, one minor thing i wonder if you could help me with, with this it unlinks and destroys perfectly, except it leaves my processes that each window was running still running, is there a way to kill those too? Or is it best to kill them individually. E.g. in one tmux window a watch script is running compiling sass and another coffeescript. If theres a way to do that with that tmux command that would be great, else thats fine it wont take much for me to just kill that process separately

Comment: Actually, found a few other people looking for the same about killing spawned processes from the tmux session (e.g. http://superuser.com/questions/611047/quit-tmux-server-and-end-all-running-processes). I'll do something similar to them for them for now, unless you have any ideas @Nick? Thanks for this though.